# Calculating non-pairwise correlation between different sets of columns of a dataset

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-corrplot, ggcorrplot

Suppose to calculate correlation of dataset `mtcars` we can use `corr <- round(cor(mtcars), 1)`, or calculate and plot a correlation matrix using `corrplot(cor(mtcars)`. However, the product is pairwise correlation. Is it possible to calculate non-pairwise correlation between spesific set of columns i.e., in mtcars correlation between columns 1:3 (`mpg, cyl, disp`) VS column 4:8 `(hp, drat, wt, qsec, vs)`.

Please suggest any method.

I have a data set containing 120 columns. I want to calculate/plot correlation matrix (Spearman correlate) of columns 1:50 with rest of the columns (i.e., 51-120). Please tell me the solution, if possible, by using `cor`, or packages i.e., `corrplot`, `ggcorrplot`.

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Easy solution is to use `cor` to calculate all correlations and then subset the result[1:50, -(1:50)]. If the data are very large, this could be problematic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using the `cor` function, just need to specify the second parameter. Example:

```
vertical_axis <- 1:3
horizontal_axis <- 4:8
corr <- cor(mtcars[, vertical_axis], mtcars[, horizontal_axis])
corrplot(corr)
```

The result:

[image: correlation plot demo]

---

**NOTE:** Using the `corrplot` function with the `order` parameter will produce errors or a wrong plot. If you need to reorder the variables (ex.: with `hclust`), reorder the correlation matrix before passing it to `corrplot`.